# What is the difference between `BOOST_ENDIAN_BIG_BYTE` and `BOOST_ENDIAN_BIG_WORD`?

Tags: c++, boost

In the latest release of boost, there are 4 endian macros defined:

```
* `BOOST_ENDIAN_BIG_BYTE`, byte-swapped big-endian.
* `BOOST_ENDIAN_BIG_WORD`, word-swapped big-endian.
* `BOOST_ENDIAN_LITTLE_BYTE`, byte-swapped little-endian.
* `BOOST_ENDIAN_LITTLE_WORD`, word-swapped little-endian.
```

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/boost/predef/other/endian.h

I'm unclear on the distinction between `_BYTE` and `_WORD` macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Word-swapped** endiannes refer to (now prehistoric) hardware which could be considered middle-endian: two halves of a word would be swapped, but byte-order in the half-word would be not. PDP-11 is probably the most famous architecture to have this.

The reason for boost to support this endiannes is unclear, to be honest, as I am pretty sure boost is generally not supported well on those prehistoric architectures. For example, C++ standard makes do with *little* and *big* options: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian

See more on middle endian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian

Comment: Thanks, so is it correct to say that all of these macros are mutually exclusive, and `#ifdef BOOST_ENDIAN_LITTLE_BYTE` should be the most common case (i.e. for intel/AMD desktops)?

Comment: @thc For intel/AMD desktops yes, BOOST_ENDIAN_LITTLE_BYTE would be the thing to see.